# Flavor transference through the air and plastic bags

Tags: organic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry

I am not sure if this is a chemistry question; however, I was wondering:

In my desk I have two plastic, zip-lock bags.  One contains cinnamon tea, the other contains nuts.

After about a week of these bags being next to each other, the flavor of the cinnamon somehow leached through both bags and now the nuts taste like cinnamon!

Is there a chemical explanation for this or isn't this a question of chemistry?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cinnamon tea is most likely flavoured with cinnamalaldehyde (**1**) and eugenol (**2**), the main components in cinnamon oil. The latter compound also gives cloves the characteristic aroma.

[image: cinnamon aroma]

To my knowledge, ziplock bags are made from polyethylene. They are not meant to be aroma-tight, like vacuum-sealed coffee packages.

Comment: No problem! Nicely flavoured question :)

Answer (score 2):

Cinnamaldehyde dissolves in and diffuses through most polymers within sensory threshold. Use glass containers with lined metal caps.  Isn't ground up tree bark amazing?

Answer (score 0):

Try taking the nuts out and putting them in a bowl or cup for a little. See if you just smelling the Cinnamon from the bag is making you "taste" it.

Just an idea.

Comment: I can try that but I am pretty certain it actually tastes like cinnamon because it doesn't taste very good.  I like cinnamon but it doesn't go well with these nuts.